# Автоматический запуск приложения при его аварийном завершении

Tags: windows, администрирование, bat, schedule

Есть приложение, написанное на Qt. Оно должно будет крутиться на сервере. приложение на данный момент не стабильное, бывает падает. Нужно что бы кто-то(что-то) отслеживало его падение и запускало процесс снова, автоматически.

Предложите свои варианты.

Comment: Не надо писать на Qt приложения, которые потом будут работать на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение не требует наличия визуального интерфейса (или он реализован отдельным модулем) - запустите его как службу и используйте штатный механизм рестарта службы при проблемах.

Comment: *"написанное на Qt"*

Comment: И что? тег "Windows" откуда-то же взялся... или приложения на QT принципиально не могут работать аки служба?

Comment: Qt - это как бы UI-библиотека

Comment: Наличие оконного интерфейса не означает, что он используется. А если используется - не факт, что нет альтернативного доступа. Опять же коли приложение работает на сервере, то велика вероятность, что наличия оператора, с ним взаимодействующего, не предусматривается, а сам интерфейс есть просто средство визуального контроля или оперативной перенастройки. Есть опять же шанс, что основной функционал сосредоточен в невизуальных модулях. В конце концов, автору решать, применим подход "ослужбевания" приложения или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Масса вариантов: глючное приложение создает Mutex, а следящее его проверяет с нужной периодичностью. Приложение упало, мьютекс исчез - запускаем заново.
Следящий процесс проверяет наличие глючного по имени, перебирая все процессы с некоторой периодичностью.
Третий - DebugAPI, но это значительно сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

В командной строке:

```
for /l %q in (0) do start /wait notepad.exe
```

под bat'ник надо немного подправить.